# Overuse of Method-chaining in Java

Tags: java, method-chaining

I see a lot of this kind of code written by Java developers and Java instructors:

```
for ( int x = 0 ; x < myArray.length ; x++ )
    accum += (mean() - myArray[x]) * (mean() - myArray[x] );
```

I am very critical of this because mean() is being invoked twice for every element in the array, when it only has to be invoked once:

```
double theMean = mean();
for ( int x = 0 ; x < myArray.length ; x++ )
    accum += (theMean - myArray[x]) * (theMean - myArray[x]);
```

Is there something about optimization in Java that makes the first example acceptable? Should I stop riding developers about this?

*** More information. An array of samples is stored as an instance variable. mean() has to traverse the array and calculate the mean every time it is invoked.

Comment: Where's the "method chaining" that you refer to in your title? That term is usually used to mean code such as `foo().bar().baz()`.

Comment: No, you shouldn't stop. I doubt that compiler optimization will take care of this since methods can have side-effects. Either way, in this case it is too risky to rely on optimization even if it *might* happen. I would definitely tell a coworker to refactor this.

Comment: It all depends on what mean() does. If it just accesses a field (as a getter would do), then optimizing it is useless: the JVM will do it for you.

Comment: @JBNizet The problem with relying on optimization here, even if it does happen, is that a future change to the method might cause it not to be optimized anymore. But then you already have this mess.

Comment: @IngoBürk agreed in that case. But I don't have the same experience as the OP. What I do often see is repeated calls to getters, and getters will almost never do something other than returning a field.

Comment: Forget optimization. You have more pressing issues on your mind. Micro optimizations like this are, in most cases, pointless. You can almost always gain considerably more performance by refactoring your architecture. If you do optimize, you should do so under the direction of a performance monitor.

Comment: @EngineerDollery This is not just an issue of performance (which I wouldn't care about too much in this case), it is also an issue of clean code. It's a form of code duplication.

Comment: Well, my example didn't show much in the way of chaining, did it? But this is the sort of strategy that results in, in my opinion, run-away chaining.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I'm sorry, but you don't get to call turning O(n^2) into O(n) a *micro* optimization, and that's exactly what may be at stake here.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Your way (second code sample) is more efficient. I don't think Java can optimize the first code sample to call `mean()` just once and re-use its return value, since `mean()` might have side effects, so the compiler can't decide to call it once if your code calls it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Leave your developers alone, it's fine -- it's readable and it works, without introducing unnecessary names and variables.

Optimization should only ever be done under the guidance of a performance monitoring tool which can show you where you're actually slow. And, typically, performance is enhanced more effectively by considering the large scale architecture of an application, not line by line bytecode optimization, which is expensive and usually unhelpful.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this because I consider this code bad code; I don't care for performance (in this aspect I definitely agree with you). However, I can't bring myself to downvote just because it's a different opinion. I think this question might just be opinion-based.

Comment: I am all for ignoring optimization in favor of readability, especially when the compiler can handle the optimization. Hence the question. But if you have an array of 500,000 elements, that's 1,000,000 unnecessary method invocations and, to calculate a mean 1,000,000 * 500,000 unnecessary calculations (accumulator += array[inx]). I think this is worth some consideration.

Comment: @IngoBürk If your `mean()` method has O(n) complexity then we're talking about much more than readability here. Eliminating a complete order of complexity does not take performance measurement to justify, either.

Comment: @IngoBürk yes, but this isn't bad code, it's good code that may be slightly inefficient.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I disagree. I think this is bad code. Not the worst one can write, but it smells nonetheless. It certainly wouldn't pass a code review in our team.

Comment: @EngineerDollery It's bad code that may be *hugely* inefficient, and since it is very easy to fix, there can't be any justification not to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your version will likely run faster, though an optimizing compiler may be able to detect if the `mean()` method returns the same value every time (e.g. if the value is hard-coded or stored in a field) and eliminate the method call.

If you are recommending this change for efficiency reasons, you may be falling foul of premature optimization. You don't really know where the bottlenecks are in your system until you *measure* in the appropriate environment under appropriate loads. Even then, improved hardware is often more cost-effective solution than developer time.

If you are recommending it because it will eliminate duplication then I think you might be on stronger ground. If the `mean()` method took arguments too, it would be especially reasonable to pull that out of the loop and call the method once and only once.

Comment: Is buying new hardware really a good alternative to pulling an invariate out of a one-line for loop?

Comment: That's invariant, not invariate. D'oh.

Comment: @Jack Well, I agree there are good reasons to pull it out that aren't about optimization. Better hardware is only meant as an example alternative to optimizing (in my opinion hardware is often not given proper consideration - possibly because developers enjoy optimizing code; I know I do). Developer time spent profiling isn't free and has an opportunity cost too.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the compiler will not optimize the method call since it cannot know whether the return value would be the same (this is especially true when `mean` processes an array as it has no way of checking whether the result can be cached). So yes the `mean()` method would be invoked twice.

In this case, if you know for sure that the array is kept the same regardless of the values of `x` and `accum` in the loop (more generally, regardless of any change in the program values), then the second code is more optimal.

Comment: The compiler can know a lot more than you think. The first step is *inlining* and once that is done, everything about the array access is known. If there is no array updating, the compiler is free to proceed with that knowledge. Note that interference from other threads does not need to be taken into account, as per the Java Memory Model (unless there are inter-thread actions involved, of course).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for the info. Is inlining a technique done by the compiler or by the JVM? As far as I know, the compiler more or less generates a "faithful" representation of the program and only does some specific type of optimizations like removing dead code.

Comment: It's done by the JVM's compiler :) It is informed by the profiling data gathered during each particular execution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some compilers will optimize this to just what you say.

Yes, you should stop riding developers about this.

I think your preferred way is better, but not mostly because of the optimization.  It is more clear that the value is the same in both places if it does not involve a method call, particularly in cases where the method call is more complex than the one you have here.

For that matter, I think it's better to write

```
double theMean = mean();
for (int x=0; x < myArray.length; x++)
{  double curValue = myArray[x];
   double toSquare = theMean - curValue;
   accum += toSquare * toSquare;
}
```

Because it makes it easier to determine that you are squaring whatever is being accumulated, and just what it is that's being sqaured.